# What to teach at schools in fantasy

Tags: magic, humans, education

Education is very common issue in fantasy, even if it is not frequently mentioned.

Old cooks teach young cooks, old witches may teach young witches. But mostly it is education master-apprentice. Sometimes (mostly in modern fantasies) there are schools for cooks or even witches (for example TV serie *The Worst witch* or czech *The Girl on the Broomstick* and its sequel *Little Witch on a Broomstick*) or so.

But what should teachers teach at *normal* (elementary, middle school, high school - not specialized as mentioned above) schools (if this education is ever mentioned)?

---

**Base**:

Iris the Flowerhair (future queen of the Fallen dragon empire) comes to predecessor of the Fallen dragon empire and finds out that local people are skilled but fully illiterate and nescient of many things. And so she decides to open school - and teach people (and she goes on even after she is elected to be queen).

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for what would be taught at a modern style magic school?

Comment: yes - but not (only) magic

Comment: We would need to know what's worth knowing so that knowing knowing what is worth knowing will help us know how to answer. Otherwise this question remains unanswerable as far as magic and mythological creatures are concerned. Although I think Harry Potter did very well with a magical school, albeit a dangerous one with no regard to the safety of students.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is a normal [curriculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Curriculum_%28England,_Wales_and_Northern_Ireland%29), with magical theory as one scientific subject among many and magic showing up from time to time in other subjects.

Consider the physics or chemistry lessons at school. They don't turn out physicists or chemists. They are meant to teach scientific method (which is often done badly) and to set a foundation of a well-rounded education. When an adult can laugh about [DHMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrogen_monoxide_hoax) or understand that high [homeopathic dilutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeopathic_dilutions) are a (possibly beneficial) [placebo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo), the chemistry teacher has done well.

Same for high school magic classes. The students would learn that magical potions exist, how an amulet works, etc. They would forget 90% after the exam and concentrate on practical things, like learning to calculate well enough so that they're not cheated by their supplier.

Answer (score 1):

The "S" key on my keyboard is currently broken and needs to be tapped more than once at the moment, o if there a typo that' probably why.

If magic is something anyone can do, it should be taught even in *all* schools. It'll probably look a lot like chemistry class, honestly, just with chemical reactions swapped with spells. Heck, magic may even be fused with the natural sciences and taught as a part of that curriculum. Even if not everyone can perform magic, there will probably be some courses on "this is what happens when a mage does this, this is what they can do, this is what they can't do, this is why" in *all* schools, whether there's a scientific explanation or it's simply up to the whims of the gods – unless, of course, it's a segregated society like in Harry Potter.

Other than that? That depends on educational ideology. Some educational institutions may teach practical skills, like carpentry, plumbing, how to repair a broken pentacle and reenchant an amulet, working with cars, etc..

Some educational institutions will focus more on liberal arts, where things may be a little bit different. At first, history will just be history, but later things will get specific: "world history," "economic history," "magical history," "religious history," "[insert country here]ian history".

There will also probably be math and physics and such. Harry Potter didn't do this, which I think is silly. Even *if* magic and technology utterly fail to work together, you're still going to have wizard economists and wizard business owners who are going to want to understand math, and wizards who want to blow things up who need to know if the blast from  this spell or another will be enough to destroy a building.

There may be specific classes dedicated to studying different types of magic, but honestly unless there's a very specific, concrete difference between the "schools of magic" and the way they're done I don't see any practical reason to separate them. In Harry Potter, you have "hexes" and "jinxes" and "transfigurations," but transfiguring someone into a rock is a perfectly good way to kill them, so what's the point? I still stand by my assertion that magic would probably be taught alongside the natural sciences, possibly with some classes having more emphasis on the magical parts than others.

It should probably look like a normal school for the most part, with magic being integrated into the math and science portions. You may think "but then only the nerds will want to do magic!" Exactly. In real life, we can break free of the atmosphere and turn lead into gold and [make electricity sing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdrqdW4Miao), yet we still look to fantasy for the fantastic. I mean, we made [*green fire that looks like something out of Harry Potter*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pl1D6oG38k) in chemistry and no one considered it terribly awesome. Kids in your world, who are constantly exposed to magic, will see it as something normal… and probably as something nerdy.